# What is wrong with my child CSS

Tags: wordpress, css

Using child CSS inside my WordPress theme I am tring to define a sub-class of

which is right aligned.

My child CSS string looks as such:

```
#p.buttons { text-align: right; }
```

And this is the string I have added to breadcrumbs.php to display the social buttons on the opposite end of the actual breadcrumbs;

```
<p class="buttons">Buttons Here</p>
```

What am I doing wrong? I understand this is a seriously trivial question so I appreciate the community's help and time.

Thank you

Comment: Remove the hash from the beginning of your selector. `#` targets an elements `id`. `p` is the tag name, not the id.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `#` from your selector:

```
p.buttons { text-align: right; }
```

`#` is used for targeting `id`. There is no id named `p` here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the # from the CSS rule.

In CSS # is used to select by id.